# are "all-male" and "all-female" opposites of androgynous?

Tags: vocabulary, antonyms

In the book *The Left Hand of Darkness* by Ursula K. Le Guin, the residents of a planet are all androgynous. Then a male human, named "Genly", arrives to this planet. I am looking for a word for his sexuality in comparison to the androgynes.

If a society has both females and males, can we call the women "all-female" when compared to androgynes?

Comment: Humans have both males and females but that doesn't mean there can't be androgynous humans. Are you confusing androgynous with single-gender?

Comment: "Androgynous" is an ambiguous term that can refer to people of indeterminate sex, people that appear to have a mix of male and female sexual characteristics, or even to clothing or attire that is suitable for both men and women. Please clarify which sense you mean, and what type of "antonym" you are looking for.

Comment: What exactly are you implying by "androgynous?" Do you mean all-male?

Comment: @sumelic Tx, good find. Typo.

Comment: @Kris: from the dictionary definition of "androgynous," I'd assume the society is entirely composed of hermaphrodites (it is fictional, after all). I'm not sure why you think it might mean all-male. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/androgynous?q=androgynous

Comment: Well, I was talking about a book named "The Left Hand of Darkness" in which the residents of a planet are all androgynous. Then a male human, named "Genly", arrives to this planet. I was looking for a word for his sexuality in comparison to the androgynes.

Comment: @sumelic I know that you know the meaning, I was addressing the OP. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antonym of an androgenous species is either "dioecious" (from the Greek of "two households") or gonochoric (from the Greek for "dispersed offspring").  These are technical terms in biology referring to sexual organs, and they can apply to species, colonies, or individuals.  Go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonochorism) for details.

You can also say that individuals are "unisexual" or "hermaphroditic."  When we speak of persons whose sex is unambiguous, we use either "female" or "male."

Note that most human beings have both a sexual identity (XX=female and XY=male chromosomal configurations) and the corresponding gender identity (i.e., which they consider themselves).  But small percentages have unusual chromosomal makeups, and a somewhat larger percentage don't feel the usual gender identification.  Human sexual characteristics are more complicated that those of plants making even physical identification difficult.  This is to say that for people, "androgynous" may encompass more traits, physical and psychological than the reproductive.